# Java dynamic method thread spawning

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

Using Java, is there a way to reference a method and have spawn off into a thread dynamically?

For example, if you have a method called `spawn()` which would take a parameter of another method reference and it would then spawn off a thread which would run the referenced method. I imagine the code would look something like:

```
void spawn(**wayToReferenceANumberOfDifferentMethods currentMethodToLaunch**) {
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            // **way to launch the currentMethodToLaunch**
        }
    }.start();
}
```

In order for the above to work, I think I would need to be able to reference a type of `method`. If this isn't possible, why is that so?

Comment: What you're trying to do, requires functions/methods to be considered first class objects in the language. Which means you can declare a function and pass it as an argument to another function. Java doesn't support this.

In java 8 however you can pass an inline body of a function with lambda expression: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking?  No.  Java is not a functional language, methods are not objects and cannot be passed as parameters.

However, this sort of general behavior can be accomplished with an `ExecutorService` and `Runnable`/`Callable`s.

Take a look at the java doc for [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

**Edit**

Also, it's possible to abstract asynchronous execution using various frameworks.  For example, using the @Async annotation in the Spring framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an object that implements Runnable to the spawn method.

```
void spawn(Runnable myRunnable) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable); 
    thread.start();
}
```

You can have multiple classes that implement the Runnable interface, each doing something different. The object you pass to the spawn method would determine which one of them would actually run.

Here is what the class that implements Runnable would look like:

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable 
{   
  public void run()     
  {
     // do what you need here
  }
}
```

Until Java 8, interfaces were used to "pass methods around", like described above. With Java 8, you have Lambda expressions, which allow you to simulate this behavior better.

Comment: I'd be cautions about a method that just spawns off a potentially unbounded number of anonymous threads and lets them loose in the runtime.  You should really use an executor service to keep track of them, it makes graceful shutdown much more straightforward.

Comment: @Aurand - that is an entirely different consideration, which is not necessarily inquired about by the OP. Whether you use the executor service or individual threads is a decision based on many factors. Without knowing exactly what this is used for, it would be very premature to declare this as a task best suited for the executor service. Also, the OP was running a thread, so I kept it as similar to his code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have indicated you probably just want to pass in `Runnable`s or `Callable`s and use those as the basis for executing the method.

However, if you really want to pass around methods than you can use the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) to accomplish this.  It's somewhat cumbersome, but it is definitely doable.

```
public void spawn(final Method callme, final Object objectThatMethodIsAMemberOf, final Object...args) {
  new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        callme.invoke(objectThatMethodIsAMemberOf, args);
      } catch(Exception e) {
        // A bunch of things can go wrong for example
        // you call the method on the wrong type of object
        // you supply the wrong number and/or type of arguments
        // the method is private and you don't have permission to call it
        // the method runs, but throws an exception
        // probably some more that I'm forgetting
      }
    }
  }.start()
}
```

Comment: This technically amounts to passing an instance of the object that this method is member of, and calling it. His questions hints more to the possibility of passing functions around, without them necessarily being tied to a class, like in pure functional languages or languages that have a decent support for the functional paradigm.